# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Tags: android, encoding, base64, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to encode and decode a String using android.util.Base64, but it gives a bad base-64 error.

The code with the problem is:

```
private byte[] base64ToByte(String str) throws IOException {

    Log.i("encription", str);
    byte[] returnbyteArray = Base64.decode(str, Base64.URL_SAFE);



    return returnbyteArray;
}
```

The error logcat is:

```
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827): Process: com.example.maptest, PID: 29827
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at com.example.maptest.security.Encription.base64ToByte(Encription.java:116)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at com.example.maptest.security.Encription.encode(Encription.java:103)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-09 13:02:18.589: E/AndroidRuntime(29827):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The input(the str String from the code) looks like this:

```
08-09 13:02:18.539: I/encription(29827): 26.919047981500626
```

It is a double converted to a string, using:

```
String.valueOf(number)
```

The error is persistent with all encoding flags (DEFAULT, NO_WRAP, etc), any help would be apreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the String value?

Comment: Try changing to `Base64.NO_WRAP`

Comment: The string value is as stated 29.919047981500626 which is the value of String str, and as i have stated i tried everything (NO_WRAP, DEFAULT, etc, etc) every single flag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to **decode** `26.919047981500626` which you can't. Because it's **not** a valid base64 encoded string.

When put into [this online base64 decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/), it gives this error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

**Update:**

If you want to know the valid formatting of a encoded base64 string, take a look at the table in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907213/336557) which shows a base64 validator code in C#.

Comment: Ok i see, but why is it not a valid Base64 string? and if not what can i use instead to fix this problem?

Comment: See my update. But I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve here... If you want a valid Base64-encoded string, just put an arbitrary string in [this site](http://www.base64encode.org/) to encode it for you.

Answer (score 9):

remove the prefix string " data:image/png;base64, ", get the string of after "data:image/png;base64,", it can decode

Answer (score 0):

It hit me, if in any case your are splitting the data & the encoding it, then decode it first before putting it back together.. Stupidly I was doing decode after collation of data that left me "bad-base-64" as each block of encode data had file enders(==).

This is [Link](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html)is handy anyways to validate the encoding and decoding.