# Play Integrity API Decryption Key: Bad base-64, with Base64.DEFAULT

Tags: kotlin, base64, google-play-integrity-api

I have checked about this answer:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217515/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bad-base-64)

However, the String format is definitely different in my project.

```
val key = "XX0XXxXXXXXxX/XXXXXX0XXX00X/0XX0xXXXX0Xxx0="
val bytes = Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

I referred to the official document:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict, in which the Verification Key is decoded properly with the same method.

Please let me know if the key might be incorrect for some reasons.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. All valid base64 (when padding is used) is a multiple of 4 characters long. You have 43.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase I used to create the public.key contains an "@", which is not a legal Base64.

**This might not be the main reason which it failed to decode**, but it was solved after removing the "@".

Comment: base64 normally supports 64 characters: 0-9, a-z, A-Z, +, -